# How to fix react-native-signature-canvas overflow on Android?

Tags: react-native

I'm having a problem that the canvas of `react-native-signature-canvas` is overflowing the screen.

[image]

I tried to use `{paddingRight: 50}` to `SignatureScreen` component but the result is white space on the right side of the image.

[image]

I tried to modify margin, position, padding, also using a parent `View` component without success. Any help is much appreciated.

I'm running the app with ExpoGo on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite with Android 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue in galaxy tab and  fixed it by adding position fixed in **m-signature-pad**.
Add this style to your **webStyle** in your **Signature** component:

```
`.m-signature-pad {
  position: fixed;
  margin:auto; 
  top: 0; 
  width:100%;
  height:50%
}
body,html { 
  position:relative; 
}`
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Also, you can center the canvas in this way:  
~~~
webStyle={`.m-signature-pad {
            position: fixed;
            margin:auto; 
            top: 0; 
            left: 5%;
            width:90%;
            height:50%;
            alignment: center;
          }
          body,html { 
            position:relative; 
          }`}
~~~

(90% of widht, 5% left margin, 5% right margin)

Thanks André

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue working fine in iOS but on Android not drawing work in my code the problem is scrollView I used this in scroll view.
Disable scroll on onBegin and enable scroll onEnd it is working for me.

```
<ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef}>
  <Header />
  <View
    style={{
      marginTop: '5%',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      height: 50,
      alignItems: 'flex-end',
    }}
  >
    <Text style={{ color: '#000' }}>Esercente la 
    Potestà/Tutore</Text>
    <Signature
      ref={ref}
      handleEnd={handleEnd}
      handleOK={handleOk}
      handleEmpty={handleEmpty}
      handleClear={handleClear}
      autoClear={false}
      descriptionText={'Signature'}
    />
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```